# Layout will not show in scrollview

Tags: android

I am adding a LinearLayout to ScrollView, but the LinearLayout will not show. It seems like a rather straighforward thing to do, so I can not really fathom what could be the matter here.

```
    ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new    FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    scroll.setLayoutParams(params);
    scroll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);

    LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    layout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);

    scroll.addView(layout);
    optionsWorkerLayout.addView(scroll);
```

Comment: How do you know its not showing? You don't have any `View`s inside the `LinearLayout`. Have you tried adding a `Button` or something to the `LinearLayout`? Also, not sure if it matters but why are you using `ScrollView.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`?

Comment: I have colored the various layouts so I know which ones are showing. I am using ScrollView.LayoutParams because I was under the impression that a view uses the type of layout params that its parent view is. Since layouts parent view is a scroll, it should take ScrollView layoutParams

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here so its hard to say without more context. Have you set breakpoints to see what happens such as checking the children inside the `View`s to see if they are getting added or if there is some exception?

Comment: After adding a button, the layout shows up. But I want it to show up with nothing in it. After all I set the width and height to match parent. So obviously there is a problem specifying the height and width of this layout. It seems that width=parent but height is wrap content, since when I added button the layout was as wide as parent, and as high as button. So maybe these layoutparams are not taking. I have tried with LinearLayout params as well.

Comment: So, you get a black background after adding the `Button` to the `LinearLayout`? Why do you want to show a blank `layout`?

Comment: Yes I see the black layout when button is added.  I want a layout with a TextView vertically centered in it. But I want the layout to be a height that is larger than textView. Either way, this should not be difficult to accomplish, but it seemingly is.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it programmatically and not creating the `layout` with an xml file? That is much easier. Also, if the `layout` shows with a `Button` but you want a `TextView`, why aren't you adding the `TextView` now?

Comment: I want to be able to specify the height of the layout. How would adding the textview change that? I am adding it programatically because I have to. The FrameLayout that is displaying this will be displaying dynamic information. The number of view and their content will change. I have been assigning any value to the height and width in LayoutParams, and nothing is taking at all.

Comment: I have been able to discern that the width value I set is respected when layout is drawn, but height is always wrap_content. When I changed to HorizontalScrollView, the height I specify is respected, but the width i specify is not respected.

Comment: ScrollView only takes on child that is always wrap_content. So to do What I want I add one Layout, and then add the ones with height X to that parent layout.